# Displacement moves my mesh away from it's position in Render Mode

Tags: node-editor, displacement

I'm experimenting with a way to procedurally create some rocks for myself, but for some reason, my rock moves slithly in Render Mode, the displacement is clearly working but I don't understand why it's moving the rock.

[image]

As you can see everything is set up but the rock moves. You can see the original outline of it in yellow. That Mix Shader leads only to the color material, nothing else is affecting it's displacement.

What's causing this?

Comment: You should plug the noise texture output into the "Height" input of a displacement node, then plug the output of this node into the displacement input of the "Material output" node

Comment: Thank you. You were correct! Please make a proper answer to that I may close this thread and approve your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should plug the noise texture output into the "Height" input of a displacement node, then plug the output of this node into the displacement input of the "Material output" node.